# not able to install pandas

Tags: python, pandas

ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Building wheel for pandas (PEP 517)  error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.19.3

Installing build dependencies ... error

ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.19.3

Comment: try to install numpy with pip and then pandas

Comment: Numpy already installed

Comment: visual studio also installed

Comment: leave VS and try using only terminal, use pip freeze to see the list of installed packages and search for numpy version